# Keep the conditional calculation result in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame `dft2022` is:

```
Start_Time     End_Time
9:55:00         10:55:00
5:41:00         14:55:00
9:01:00         12:55:00
9:02:00         7:55:00
8:55:00          N/A
11:55:00         N/A
```

I want to add a duration column in this dataframe, the duration = End_Time - Start_Time. I used the following:

```
dft2022["duration"] = pd.to_datetime(dft2022["End_Time"]) - pd.to_datetime(dft2022["Start_Time"])
```

However, I only want to keep the "duration" value where `End_Time - Start_Time` is positive value or doesn't have a `N/A` in End_Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output that you expect is unclear, bit you could use `clip` to set the negative deltas to 0:

```
df['duration'] = (pd.to_datetime(dft2022["End_Time"])
 .sub(pd.to_datetime(dft2022["Start_Time"]))
 .clip(lower='0')
 )
```

Output:

```
  Start_Time  End_Time        duration
0    9:55:00  10:55:00 0 days 01:00:00
1    5:41:00  14:55:00 0 days 09:14:00
2    9:01:00  12:55:00 0 days 03:54:00
3    9:02:00   7:55:00 0 days 00:00:00
4    8:55:00       NaN             NaT
5   11:55:00       NaN             NaT
```

To filter the date, you can use:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(dft2022["End_Time"])
     .sub(pd.to_datetime(dft2022["Start_Time"]))
     .gt('0')]
```

Output:

```
  Start_Time  End_Time
0    9:55:00  10:55:00
1    5:41:00  14:55:00
2    9:01:00  12:55:00
```

Comment: Thank you. It gave me the error: "Unknown string format: N/A". I know it's because my N/As are all in string format. How do I change them to a time format?

Comment: you can use `df = df.replace({'N/A', pd.NA})` as a first step

Comment: Sorry. the "Unknown string format: N/A" still exist

Comment: Alternative, use the `errors='coerce'` option in `pandas.to_datetime`

Answer (score 1):

Can try something like this, needs Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Start_Date': ['9:55:00',  '5:41:00', '9:01:00', '9:02:00', '8:55:00', '11:55:00'], 'End_Date': ['10:55:00', '14:55:00', '12:55:00', '7:55:00', 'N/A', 'N/A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['_end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.End_Date, errors='coerce')
df['_start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Date, errors='coerce')
# Coerce sets NaT if unable to parse as datetime.

df["duration"] = np.where(
    df._end_time >= df._start_time,
    df._end_time - df._start_time,
    pd.NaT
)
df.drop(columns=['_start_time', '_end_time'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Start_Date  End_Date        duration
0    9:55:00  10:55:00   3600000000000
1    5:41:00  14:55:00  33240000000000
2    9:01:00  12:55:00  14040000000000
3    9:02:00   7:55:00             NaT
4    8:55:00       N/A             NaT
5   11:55:00       N/A             NaT
```